# Pro/cons: Multiple lists or one big list with multiple views?

Tags: 2010, list, list-view, architecture, information-architecture

I have data that can go through different stages, during which it will have common fields and fields that are only used on specific stages.

If I e.g. have these fields: `CommenField1, CommenField2, StageA1, StageA2, StageB1, StageB2`

They could either exists two individual lists, i.e. `A` and `B` like so:

- `A = CommenField1, CommenField2, StageA1, StageA2`
- `B = CommenField1, CommenField2, StageB1, StageB2`

Or as a single larger list with all fields and with views that shows the same fields as the lists `A` and `B`.

What is the common choice between the two options, and what are the pros/cons between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I had the same question with you. First, I did it using 7 lists first, like using database tables :) I tried to do all needings through workflows. But it really disappointed me :( I had so many synchronization problems. So i changed the architecture to use one big list and now we are using it. It is working now on production and I have just a few problems but not big deals.

Thus, I hardly recommend that use one big list with multiple views. Also you can use InfoPath to customize your forms.